# What is the Uniswap V3 Swap Router on Arbitrum Goerli

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, uniswap

I am looking for the Uniswap SwapRouter02 for arbitrum goerli I do not see it on this list of addresses.

https://github.com/Uniswap/sdk-core/blob/main/src/addresses.ts

Does anyone know where it may be and or if it is not deployed on arbitrum goerli?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried going to this url to find the address

https://github.com/Uniswap/sdk-core/blob/main/src/addresses.ts

As well as going to their different npm packages and repos/ tests I have not found the address on any of these yet.